# Insert data through ajax into mysql database

Tags: php, ajax

Newsletter:

```
<form id="form-search" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <span><span class="style2">Enter you email here</span>:</span>
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" required/>

 <input type="submit" value="subscribe" class="submit" onclick="return fun()" />
                        </form>
                        <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","","");
mysql_select_db("");
error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);

$email=$_POST['email'];
$sql="INSERT INTO newsletter_email(email) VALUES ('$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
echo "You have been successfully subscribed.";
}
 if(!$sql)
die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

?>
```

But I want to insert my E-Mail to database through Ajax. I don't want my page to get redirected, because every time the page got refreshed, null value got inserted to the database..

I just want my E-mail got inserted to database through Ajax, and after that the email box
i.e.

```
<input name="email" type="email" id="email" required/>  
<input type="submit" value="subscribe" class="submit" onclick="return fun()" />
```

should get disappeared and there should be the line "you've been successfully subscribed" ..

Any brief code will be very useful.. thank u in advance :)

Comment: did you tried anything. adding ajax in you code

Comment: Use `PDO` or `mysqli` functions, because mysql_* is deprecated

Comment: sarmishtha : are you sure you need ajax for this?as i can see there is no need of ajax.

Comment: @MazIqbal yup, but i m not very  handy in ajax, so could not get through it

Comment: @Mrcoder but any other method i mean anything in php ll make my page redirected na .. that i dont want

Comment: Your code is insecure. This is obviously new to you, so just keep on learning, but keep that in mind before you put it on the internet.

Comment: actualy m new.. can u help me with this 1 @SverriM.Olsen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $(document).on('click','#save',function(e) {
  var data = $("#form-search").serialize();
  $.ajax({
         data: data,
         type: "post",
         url: "insertmail.php",
         success: function(data){
              alert("Data Save: " + data);
         }
});
 });
```

and in `insertmail.php:`

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST))
{
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("eciticket_db");
error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);

$email=$_POST['email'];
$sql="INSERT INTO newsletter_email(email) VALUES ('$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
echo "You have been successfully subscribed.";
}
}
?>
```

Don't use `mysql_` it's deprecated.

`another method:`

Actually if your problem is null value inserted into the database then try this and here no need of ajax.

```
<?php
if($_POST['email']!="")
{
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("eciticket_db");
    error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO newsletter_email(email) VALUES ('$email')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if($result){
    //echo "You have been successfully subscribed.";
              setcookie("msg","You have been successfully subscribed.",time()+5,"/");
              header("location:yourphppage.php");
    }
     if(!$sql)
    die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close();
}
?>
    <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['msg'])){?>
       <span><?php echo $_COOKIE['msg'];setcookie("msg","",time()-5,"/");?></span> 
    <?php }?>
<form id="form-search" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <span><span class="style2">Enter you email here</span>:</span>
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="subscribe" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: cant i do this without the action page ?? i mean i dnt want any page redirection

Comment: This things happen without page reloding.It's only post data to another page and then insert that data and then alert the message.

Comment: the problem is , the subscription is not happening, the submit button is not working

Comment: remove `onclick="return fun()"` from submit button.

Comment: write `print_r($_POST);` on top of the page and see what is the result?

Comment: hey solved... but u knw if i want to make disappear my input box n der i need to display the line you got subscribed.. i ve to use ajax, rite ??

Comment: no, not actually.you can use `cookies` for that.see updated answer.

Comment: Can we Send Array in response?

Comment: @ankitsuthar, send json from php page and parse that json in js.

Comment: $(document).on('click','#save',function(e) you have not create save as id so what it is mean?

Comment: @maheshgupta there is 2 diff. answers. If you want to use first one then there should be "Save" as id in your button.

Answer (score 3):

The ajax is going to be a javascript snippet that passes information to a small php file that does what you want. So in your page, instead of all that php, you want a little javascript, preferable jquery:

```
function fun()
{
    $.get('\addEmail.php', {email : $(this).val()}, function(data) {
        //here you would write the "you ve been successfully subscribed" div
    });
}
```

also you input would have to be:

```
<input type="button" value="subscribe" class="submit" onclick="fun();" />
```

last the file addEmail.php should look something like:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("eciticket_db");

error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);

$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$sql="INSERT INTO newsletter_email(email) VALUES ('$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
echo "You have been successfully subscribed.";
}
 if(!$sql)
die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();
```

Also sergey is right, you should use mysqli. That's not everything, but enough to get you started.

Comment: should i just put my normal div regarding "you ve been successfully subscribed"

Comment: not sure what you mean but you can do it a number of ways. Maybe just enclose the whole ting in a div and change the html. Again, you'll probably need to get to know some more jQuery if you don't know it already.

Comment: listen i just want to insert the email id to my database through ajax, i dnt want my page to be redirected..

Comment: yeah, the page won't submit if you change the input to `type="button"` like I referenced. In fact you dont even need the `<form id="form-search" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">` line at this point.

Comment: that subscribe button is not working ... i m extremely sorry if m bothering you very much

Comment: There is no redirection. did you put anything in the comments part of this: `$.get('\addEmail.php', {email : $(this).val()}, function(data) {
        //here you would write the "you ve been successfully subscribed" div
    });`

Answer (score 2):

Why use normal jquery ajax feature. Why not use jquery ajax form plugin, which post the form data by ajax to the form action link.

Check it here:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

It is very easy to use and support several data formats including json, html xml etc. Checkout the example and you will find it very easy to use.

Thank you

Comment: but i dont want any alert box na

Comment: it is upto you to use an alert box or not. If success section you can display a message directly on the page by showing a div or redirect the user to another page. There they just showed an example with an alert box.

Answer (score 0):

ajax:

```
$(document).on('click','#mv_secure_page',function(e) {
    var data = $("#m_form1").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        url: "adapter.php",
        success: function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data);
        }
    });
});
```

php code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Engg Amjad
 * Date: 11/9/16
 * Time: 1:28 PM
 */


if(isset($_REQUEST)){
    include_once('inc/system.php');

    $full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
    $business_name=$_POST['business_name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO mars (f_n,b_n,em,p_n,msg) values('$full_name','$business_name','$email','$phone','$message') ";

    $sql_result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($sql_result){
       echo "inserted successfully";
    }else{
        echo "Query failed".mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The available answers led to the fact that I entered empty values into the database. I corrected this error by replacing the serialize () function with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// When click the button.
$("#button").click(function() {

    // Assigning Variables to Form Fields
    var email = $("#email").val();

    // Send the form data using the ajax method
    $.ajax({
        data: "email=" + email,
        type: "post",
        url: "your_file.php",
        success: function(data){
            alert("Data Save: " + data);
        }
    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you steps how you can insert data in ajax using PHP

AJAX Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertData() {
var student_name=$("#student_name").val();
var student_roll_no=$("#student_roll_no").val();
var student_class=$("#student_class").val();


// AJAX code to send data to php file.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert-data.php",
        data: {student_name:student_name,student_roll_no:student_roll_no,student_class:s
         tudent_class},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
         $("#message").html(data);
        $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
        },
        error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
        }
    });

 }

</script>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

include('db.php');
$student_name=$_POST['student_name'];
$student_roll_no=$_POST['student_roll_no'];
$student_class=$_POST['student_class'];

$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO 
student(student_name,student_roll_no,student_class) 
VALUES(:student_name, :student_roll_no,:student_class)");

 $stmt->bindparam(':student_name', $student_name);
 $stmt->bindparam(':student_roll_no', $student_roll_no);
 $stmt->bindparam(':student_class', $student_class);
 if($stmt->execute())
 {
  $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
  echo json_encode($res);
  }
  else {
  $error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur.";
  echo json_encode($error);
  }



  ?>
```

You can customize it according to your needs. you can also check complete steps of [AJAX Insert Data PHP](http://www.phpcodify.com/insert-data-in-php-using-jquery-ajax-without-page-refresh/)