# insert data in database through ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to insert data through Ajax

Can anyone help me .. I want to insert data in database using Ajax in php

My table name in database is `post` and my fields are `register_id`, `post_data`, `time`

```
 <form class="form center-block" method="post" action="actionpost.php">           
      <textarea class="form-control input-lg" name="post_data" autfofocus placeholder="What do you want to share?"></textarea>
      <button name="submit" >Post</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming-related question? This site is for programming questions, not a place to dump your to-do list.

Comment: If you google the question title `insert data in database through ajax in php` you will get 100's of working examples

Comment: Your question is quite broad covering a whole range of tasks.  Take @Shehary's advice and google first.  Attempt a solution and come back here with specific problems.  Good luck!

Comment: does't found any example :O

Comment: Here, it will be a good start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769364/insert-data-through-ajax-into-mysql-database