# Keeping Current URL after form submit PHP

Tags: php, html

Say I have e.g: **(foo.com/index.php?a=1)** and a form on it to submit data, but when the submit is hit the url refreshes and it gets rid of the values from the attached.

How do I make the url on my page to stay same as before even when the sumbit button is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: You can use ajax... http://stackoverflow.com/a/20769461/797495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this: `action="yourpage.php?var1=value1&var2=value2"`. You can get these with PHP like so: `$var1 = $_GET['var1']`.

Example:

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage.php?var1=value1&var2=value2">
[...]
</form>
```

You can do this to add existing variables into the url:

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage.php?var1=<?php echo $_POST['var1'];?>&var2=<?php echo $_POST['var2'];?>">
[...]
</form>
<!-- Output:
<form method="post" action="yourpage.php?var1=value1&var2=value2">
[...]
</form>
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the form action in the HTML to post. i.e.:

```
<form action="..." method="post">
```

Assuming its a get at the moment. Then set action to your URL