# input tag data insertion to Database using Ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

hi I was trying to insert `input` tag value into MySQL using Ajax since most of the operation is going in **js** I tried with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769364/insert-data-through-ajax-into-mysql-database). now don't know what is going on, it's not doing anything I checked console its shows nothing here...I tried this code in multiple projects and there it was working.
any help or alternative way would be appreciated. Thanks
here are my codes files.
`test.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="./jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="enter name">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").on('keypress',function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            var strr = $("#name").val();
            console.log(strr);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'testinsert.php',
                data: $('#name').val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( response){
                console.log( 'the feedback from your result.php: ' + response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`testinsert.php`

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST))
{
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("usr");
error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);

$email=$_POST['name'];
$sql="INSERT INTO at_user(user) VALUES ('$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
echo "You have been successfully subscribed.";
}
}
?>
```

**here is output of console**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx0OE.png)

Comment: Please use entire form  tag instead of just only take input , after taking form provide `id` attribute to form after edit your question

Comment: Take a look at your browser's DevTools Network tab to see what data gets sent to your script. Does `$_POST['name']` exist? Where do you set `name`?

Comment: Consider rewording the question line as a question.

Comment: @kerbholz I check error 500 to my script but i got param `$_POST['name']`

Comment: "_but i got param $_POST['name']_" I bet you don't: `data: $('#name').val()` says you're sending a _string_ with the value of the field `#name`, no 'name' key here. Take a look at @JatinKaklotar s answer

Comment: I already implemented his answer

Comment: @kerbholz I am receiving proper value of my text `input` tag

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace below line from ajax script

**from**

```
  data: $('#name').val(),
```

**to**

```
  data: {name : $('#name').val()},
```